# PHP global variable available to application and other users

Tags: php, global-variables

PHP Global Variable

1. Are they available application wide e.g: if they are created on
   index.php are they values available in file.php
2. Is the value of the global variable same for each user. Say I have
   one user doing something and his global variable value is 1. Will
   the second user who visits the same page his value also be 1?
   edited:
3. Taking the advice from here: I have decided to use **value by reference**
4. **Result I need to achieve is:**
5. New session should have the same results and $name variable in any other file not included should not be associated with this variable.

> name: initial vj name: vj name: vj name in file2: vj

Code:

---

```
<?php 

$name ;
$name ='initial vj';

echo '<br/>name: ' .$name;

test($name);

function test(&$name)
{

    $name = 'vj';
    echo '<br/>name: ' .$name;
}


echo '<br/>name: ' .$name;


include('file2.php');

?>
```

```
<?php

$name;

echo '<br />name in file2: ' .$name;


?>
```

Comment: 1. no 2. no​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Use sessions to persist across pages, will be different per user.  To have the same per user use database storage or similar.

Comment: All variables are temporary for the current request only. You should not use globals (search and you'll find a lot on the subject)

Comment: If you are looking for that i suggest you look into $_SESSION[]  , session variables..

Comment: You could have index with the defined variable and throught include( file.php ) or requiere( file.php ) to access the variable, you could also use SESSION or save the variable in a temp mysql table and then you could access it between multiple users and applications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This concept is called "application scope."  PHP is better equipped for a scope of session, request or page.  To place data within application scope in PHP, it's more common to make a database call to get the value.

We can use superglobals like $_SESSION, $_REQUEST or $_POST and $_GET to assign the variable to live beyond just one page, inside the session, request or page scopes.  PHP doesn't have a common, similar method for assigning a value to a variable in application scope.  Instead, application scopes are often imitated by calling an outside source of data, like a database or file.  Earlier versions of PHP had some features that leaned toward the concept of application scope, but they have been deprecated.

For your questions:

1. The question shows the idea of an application scope variable.  For example, if you wanted every user to enter a value on index.php and write it to database, then it would be possible to make a call during the creation of file.php that would retrieve that value.

Instead of doing this for all users by one user, we often write this kind of code as a $_SESSION variable, usable by one user at a time. It is common for us to use a database write and a database read to solve this kind of problem.  Simply put down the value by the user who writes it.  Get it for the readers.

2. This is the concept of a static application-scoped variable.  To achieve this, simply have both users make similar database calls to retrieve the same value.

There is a super-global named $GLOBALS, but it is more of a shortcut for annotating how a variable is named.  It's not a feature that will bring application scope to the variable.

JSP allows the use of application scoped variables by simple declaration. ASP allows the use of application scoped variables through application configuration with XML.  PHP doesn't directly use application scope in the context of a variable, object or class.

[php man scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)
[php man reserved](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php)

[jsp application scope](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html)
[jsp application scope](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/Servlets5.html#wp64315)

[ms kb asp application scope variables](https://web.archive.org/web/20150408121616/http://support.microsoft.com:80/en-us/kb/309018)
[php man superglobals](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)

Answer (score 1):

Global does not imply that the variables are available to everyone in the world.  Global refers to all the objects in that session.  The sessions do not communicate with each other.  It would kind of be a nightmare if they did do that.

If you have a variable that you need to share all around, you should have it saved in a database, and each of the users will call that variable up to make use of it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use global variables if you value your sanity. And God forbid they someday are as you were thinking.

Yes, a global variable declared in index.php is available in file.php. And this is where the problem begins. Assume you have an error in the value of a global variable, say $myGlobal.

1. How would you know where this wrong value was introduced, if any file may change the variable of $myGlobal? (Consider the fact that a complex web application may have hundreds, sometimes thousands, of files.)
2. In what point would you monitor the value of $myGlobal to debug your program?

This is just one point against global variables. There are many other.

If things were as you said, if a global variable could be shared by all sessions, the mess would be even greater. Thanks God, and language designers too, that global variables are global **only in the scope of a session**.

Answer (score -1):

write on a txt file then read it when needed.

```
$yourvalue=202406;
file_put_contents('global.txt',$yourvalue);

//read when needed
$yourvalue=file_get_contents('global.txt')
```